# Swift Navigating to ViewController thats 3 windows deep

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController that I want to present when a push notification is opened from the locked screen.
The view controller is embedded inside a chain of view controllers, the chain is:

TabbedBarController(root) -> NavigationController0 -> ViewController0 -> ViewController1 -> ViewControllerIWant

I have two variables from the push notification I want to pass into ViewControllerIWant

So far I have:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC") as! UITabBarController // HomeVC is the TabbedBarController
let NaviVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavigationController0") as! UINavigationController // NavigationController0 is the Navigation Controller for this stack

let ViewController0 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController0") as ViewController0
let ViewController1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as ViewController1
let ViewControllerIWant = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerIWant") as ViewControllerIWant 

// Pass the Variables into ViewControllerIWant
ViewControllerIWant.Variable0 = "This is the first Variable"
ViewControllerIWant.Variable1 = "this is the second variable"
// Load the VC
self.presentViewController(ViewControllerIWant, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

I can load ViewControllerIWant directly but then loose the navigation and tab controllers so moving backwards requires you yo close the app and reload.
How do I nest the VC's so that when the user swipes this notification it loads ViewControllerIWant ?

Comment: Set up all the VCs using the `present` and `push` methods as appropriate, passing `animated:false`. (Use `true` for presenting/pushing `ViewControllerIWant`.)

Comment: just set the viewControllers property on your navigation controller to your array of 3 vc's

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the `viewControllers` of the navigationController. And show the current navigationController.

In your example you should add this after the line will be (I have change all to a lowercase. You really shouldn't be using a uppercase as variable)

```
viewControllerIWant.variable1 = "this is the second variable"
naviVC.viewControllers = [viewController0, viewController1, viewControllerIWant]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your navigation controller by using segues instead of presenting the View Controller

Once the segue is created from your starting VC into your desired VC, you give it an identifier (e.g. "segueFromVC1ToVCIWant").

Then call the method as an action of your notification:

```
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueFromVC1ToVCIWant", sender: nil)
```

Finally can pass the variables like this:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "segueFromVC1ToVCIWant"){
            let viewControllerIWant = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerIWant
            ViewControllerIWant.variable0 = self.variable0
            ViewControllerIWant.variable1 = self.variable1
    }
}
```

Make sure you create variables with the same name in ViewControllerIWant in order to receive the values.

Comment: So AppDelegate doesnt have a method to Segue